# Android View width and height have not changed after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-view

I have an activity whose layout I need to change after a rotation and part of the layout is a graph that is drawn using the width and height of the view that it will be placed into. The first time my code runs, the graph is drawn correctly, however after the rotation the width and height of the container view are not correct, in fact they appear to be the view as if it was not rotated.

Here is what I have so far,

- In my manifest for the activity I am working:

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

- In my activity I have these following methods:

onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    patient_id = extras.getInt("patient_id");
    patient_name = extras.getString("patient_name");
    historyDurationType = 12;

    constructLayout();
}
```

constructLayout

```
public void constructLayout(){
    if(landScape){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bg_history_static_land);

        //Set buttons
        btnTwelve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwelveHoursLand);
        btnTwentyFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwentyFourHoursLand);
        btnSeven= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSevenDaysLand);

        btnTwelve.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwentyFour.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSeven.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnTwelve.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue_regular));
        btnTwentyFour.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
        btnSeven.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);         
    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bg_history_static);
        //Set buttons
        btnTwelve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwelveHours);
        btnTwentyFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwentyFourHours);
        btnSeven= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSevenDays);

        btnTwelve.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwentyFour.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSeven.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnTwelve.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue_regular));
        btnTwentyFour.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
        btnSeven.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);

        btnComment = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCommentGraph);
        btnComment.setOnClickListener(this);

         populateOtherContent(officialReadings12);
         TextView tvStats = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatistics);
         Typeface chunkFiveFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/chunkfivettfversion.ttf");
         tvStats.setTypeface(chunkFiveFont);

         TextView tvReading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtReadingTitle);
         tvReading.setTypeface(chunkFiveFont);
         comment = null;
    }

    if(needData){
        getLatestReadings();
    }  

    populateGraph();
}
```

populateGraph

```
public void populateGraph(){
    if(landScape){
        graph_container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.graph_land_content_layout);
    }else{
        graph_container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.graph_content_layout);
    }

    //Create graphlayout        
    mainGraph_Layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams glParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mainGraph_Layout.setId(909);
    mainGraph_Layout.setLayoutParams(glParams);
    graph_container.addView(mainGraph_Layout);


    graph_container.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if(needsGraph){
                layoutGraph();
                needsGraph = false;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

layoutGraph

```
public void layoutGraph(){      

    viewWidth = mainGraph_Layout.getWidth();
    viewHeight = mainGraph_Layout.getHeight();

     //MORE STUFF IS HERE BUT NOT IMPORTANT

}
```

onConfigurationChanged

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        //Config is landscape here          
        actionBar.hide();
        needData = false;
        landScape = true;
        needsGraph = true;
        constructLayout();
    }else{
        //Config is portrait here
        actionBar.show();
        needData = false;
        landScape = false;
        needsGraph = true;
        constructLayout();
    }
}
```

After rotation, it is at the layoutGraph() viewWidth and viewHeight objects where I have the problem. I had assumed by that point (having used the global layout listener) that the values would be correct. My understanding was that the listener would only have been triggered once "graph_container" was completed (and landscape or portrait) and so when calling layoutGraph() the width and height of "mainGraph_layout" (a child a graph_container, widths and heights set to MATCH_PARENT) would be good to go. It appears that the width and height I am getting are as if the phone is still portrait, and worth noting it appears that the removal of the action bar has also been taken into account.

Sorry for the long question but I thought it best to show all the code. If anything else needs to be shown then please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much better way to do this.

**Use resource folders**

Put your default layout files in `res/layout`, and the ones for landscape in `res/layout-land`. In other words, move `res/layout/activity_bg_history_static_land.xml` to `res/layout-land/activity_bg_history_static.xml`.

In `onCreate`, call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_bg_history_static);
```

The system will pick the file from `res/layout-land` when you are in landscape orientation, `res/layout` otherwise.

If you have views that are only present in one layout but not the other e.g. the comment button, wrap the code inside a null check like this:

```
btnComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCommentGraph);
if (btnComment != null) {
  btnComment.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

For `populateGraph()`, make sure both `res/layout/activity_bg_history_static.xml` and `res/layout-land/activity_bg_history_static.xml` has `android:id="@+id/R.id.graph_content`. Then you can do `findViewById(R.id.graph_content)` and get the `LinearLayout` you need.

**Save data across rotation**

In your activity, override `onSaveInstanceState()`, and save the data from `getLatestReadings()` into the bundle.

Then, in `onCreate`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
  getLatestReadings();
} else {
  // Restore latest readings from savedInstanceState
}
```

With that, you can let the system handle the rotation i.e. remove this from your manifest:

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Since the system is handling the rotation, you don't need to have a view tree observer any more. And you don't have to override `onConfigurationChanged`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have followed it and solved my problem as well as cleaned up my code. The only thing I haven't done yet is handle the onSavedInstanceState aspect as I need to make my custom objects (from getLatestReadings() ) parcelabl but it looks like the right direction to take.